# Full Forms (somehow related to Computers)

Tags: discussion

Can I ask stuff like full forms of somethings in the computer science stack exchange, for example, the full form of Wi-Fi or internet?
I won't really only ask this but some more also.
So my question is can I ask full forms of computer related stuff?

Comment: What does "full form" mean?  I don't think I've ever heard that term before.

Comment: Did u mean "u have ever heard of the term full form"?

 - I mean by full form u will get it by this example: 

the full form of "Wi-Fi" is "Wireless Fidelity"

Answer (score 5):

If you're asking about specific computer technology or products, I don't think it's on-topic here.  We're about computer science rather than specific products or technologies.  That's just my opinion; others might have a different opinion.

Comment: I mean like the full form of "Wi-Fi" is "Wireless Fidelity". I want to ask this... yeah u got it ill answer my own question if it's on topic :P

Comment: @ACoolGuy,  That sounds like a question about a specific computer technology, so doesn't sound likely to be on-topic here.  In my opinion.  Others might disagree.

Comment: Separately: we expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, to make sure that the question isn't already answered in standard places.  For the specific example you mention, there's an entire Wikipedia article on Wi-Fi (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi).  Morever, while Wi-Fi might once have been an abbreviation of Wireless Fidelity, it's not clear that Wi-Fi is actually an abbreviation  -- it seems to be a trade name of its own. See, e.g., https://boingboing.net/2005/11/08/wifi-isnt-short-for.html.

Comment: umm, thx I really didn't know about that, that means I NEED TO DO MORE RESEARCH DUMB ME! Thx @D.W. :D

Comment: Agreed. However, a question like "What does PCP in PCP theorem mean? Clearly not Post Correspondence Problem!" would be  a valid [tag:terminology] question on [cs.SE].

Comment: @Raphael do u mean that my question fits this page?

Comment: @ACoolGuy The one about "WiFi"? No.

Comment: @Raphael the Question will be like this:
Q. What Are The Full Forms OF These Abbreviations?

1) COMPUTER
2) LAPTOP
3) DESKTOP
e.t.c